# Importing CSV to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv, import

Hi I'm trying to import csv to dumpWS.
When I cancel the file open this code works fine but when I select the csv.file then open. This code gives me run-time error '13' type missmatch.

The line it has problem with is "If strFile = False Then"

Private Sub CSV_Import()

```
Dim addDumpWS As Worksheet
Dim dumpWS As Worksheet, strFile As String

Set dumpWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DUMP")

' Clear all data in worksheet(DUMP) before import
dumpWS.Cells.Clear

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")

' Message box when file is not selected
If strFile = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Select
    Range("ImportStatus").Select
    MsgBox "No file selected. Cannot continue import."
    Exit Sub

Else
' Import select csv
    With dumpWS.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=dumpWS.Range("A1"))
         .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
         .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
         .Refresh
    End With

' Copy imported data to WebDBDataBody
dumpWS.Activate
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
Selection.Copy

Range("WebDBDataBody").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

' Recorded Imported Date
Range("ImportedDate").Value = Date
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: because strFile is likely declared as a string, right?  False is boolean data, not a string.

Comment: I guess you are right. As I researched I found two solution. Either change strFile as variant or state False as Cstr(Flase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

If strFile = False Then

to
If strFile = Cstr(False) Then

and it worked fine